# HTML/CSS sign up form

Tags: html, css, label

I am currently working on creating a sign up form html/css. I realised that different browsers work differently on the width of inputs. How can i rectify this issue and make sure that my sign up form is compatible with all browsers. My sign up form works perfectly for chrome as it is where i do coding on.

```css
ul {
  background-color: #000000;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #0cf72a;
}
.word-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}
.word-container h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ab0a0a;
}
.register-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.fname input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 115px;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
}
.lname input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 314px;
  top: -5.5px;
  padding: 8px;
}
.userid input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 115px;
  padding: 8px;
  top: 10px;
}
.pwd input[type="password"] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px;
  left: 115px;
  top: 25px;
}
.email input[type="email"] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px;
  left: 115px;
  top: 40px;
}
.btn button[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 115px;
  top: 55px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 382px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ab0a0a;
}
div.btn button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="word-container">
  <h1>Create your account</h1>
</div>
<div class="register-container">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="fname">
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" size="20">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="lname">
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" size="20">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="userid">
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userid" size="50">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="pwd">
      <label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" size="50">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" size="50">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad in its current form. Can you describe exactly where widths go wrong, in which browsers, and isolate the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: For a layout like this, you need to stay far away from position relative and absolute. You can easily do this with a static layout (and using flex it is even easier).

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to use something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or any other CSS reset code ([eric meyer css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is very popular too) to reset CSS across all browsers.

Any browser come with it's defaults values for padding's,margins,widths, heights etc...

I guess it won't be an 100% solution but it will defiantly will take you closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do not jump to position relative and absolute. If you are new to all this, I can understand it seems the most natural way to go about positioning elements; just using a top and left position and that's that. But this is not how you should do it on the web!

Below you can find how I would do it.

Matan G. is right in pointing out that a CSS reset/normalize is often used, and I do so myself as well. However, before you do that (and considering you're new) it would be wise to take a look at the code that I posted and see if it makes any sense to you. If not, ask.

It is important to note that you should **avoid** these things when possible:

- setting a fixed width to text items such as headings, paragraphs, lists.
- using relative/absolute positioning. They are very useful but only when necessary.
- using too many divs/classes than actually needed. Don't overcrowd your HTML.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
ul {
  background-color: #000000;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #0cf72a;
}
.word-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 80px auto auto;
}
.word-container h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ab0a0a;
}
.register-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
.name::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.name label:first-child {
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.name label {
 width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px);
 float: left;
}
input, [type="submit"] {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
[type="submit"] {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ab0a0a;
  margin: 0;
}
[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="word-container">
  <h1>Create your account</h1>
</div>
<div class="register-container">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="name">
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
      </label>
    </div>
      <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userid">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML Forms</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            width: 45%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .form-content{
            margin: 40px;
        }
        .form-content input{
            width: 100%;
        }

        label{
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input[type=text],[type=email],[type=tel],[type=date],[type=password]{
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #D9F1F7;
            border: #000000;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        input[type=submit]{
            background: #4C63ED;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        input[type=submit]:hover{
            background: #330EEF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <form name="signup" method="get" action="">
            <div class="form-content">
                <label>First Name : </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <label>Last Name : </label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <label>E-Mail : </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <label>Telephone : </label>
                <input type="tel" name="telephone" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <label>Date of Birth : </label>
                <input type="date" name="dob" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-content">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```